# How do I count the user input in a while loop to stop at 10 inputs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have recently started creating a Python program for my coursework.
I have pretty much the main skeleton of the program but I have created a while loop and I need it to stop when the user enters ten words/definitions.
I have looked about on stackoverflow and everything I have tried hasn't really worked.
Anyway, hopefully some helpful people can give help me out.

```
def teacher_enter_words():
    done = False
    print 'Hello, please can you enter a word and definition pair.'

    while not done:
            word = raw_input('\nEnter a word: ')
            deff = raw_input('Enter the definition: ')
            # append a tuple to the list so it can't be edited.
            words.append((word, deff))
            add_word = raw_input('Add another word? (y/n): ')
            if add_word.lower() == 'n':
                    print "Thank you for using the Spelling Bee program! The word(s) and definition(s) will now appear when a student logs in.\n"
                    done = True
```

Comment: You just need to add a check `while len(words) < 10 or not done:` that should do it. Of course before the while loop starts, you need `words = []` but I think you had that already and maybe forgot to add it in your code snippet.

Comment: Yeah I already had the words = [], but thank you anyway I really appreciate it! That will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

```
def enterWords(maxWords):
  done = False
  words = []
  while len(words) < maxWords and not done:
    word = raw_input('\nEnter a word: ')
    deff = raw_input('Enter the definition: ')
    words.append((word, deff))
    add_word = raw_input('Add another word? (y/n): ')
    if add_word.lower() == 'n':
      print "Thank you for using the Spelling Bee program! The word(s) and definition(s) will now appear when a student logs in.\n"
      done = True
  return words
```

Comment: I think that using the while loop to check whether you have enough words is a better design than trying to break out of an infinite loop.

Comment: @GustavBertram: I don't have an infinite loop in here. Did I miss something?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I was trying to point out why **I like this answer** better than the other one.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I think that Gustav meant that your approach is better then if - break, Which i have to agree, the reason i didn't do that in my solution is to make it simple.

Comment: @GustavBertram: oh! Sorry about the confusion... and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare `words` list currently.

You can check the size of `words` using `len()` so if you have 10 words you can exit the 
loop.

This can be done also without using `done` variable, you can set the while loop condition to be `len(words) < 10` so you can save the use of `done`

```
def teacher_enter_words():
    done = False
    print 'Hello, please can you enter a word and definition pair.'

    words = []

    while not done:
            word = raw_input('\nEnter a word: ')
            deff = raw_input('Enter the definition: ')
            # append a tuple to the list so it can't be edited.
            words.append((word, deff))
            if len(words) == 10:
                print "Hi you have 10 words!!!"
                break
            add_word = raw_input('Add another word? (y/n): ')
            if add_word.lower() == 'n':
                    print "Thank you for using the Spelling Bee program! The word(s) and definition(s) will now appear when a student logs in.\n"
                    done = True

    print words
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly, been stuck on this problem for a while now and now I've learnt how to do it for future purposes! Cheers.